# Can you be IP address-banned from registering?

Tags: support, sign-up, ip-ban, tor

Sometimes when I tried to use [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) for privacy to sign up, I would get a message along the lines of *You cannot register at this time. If this error persists contact us.* Given that this error can sometimes be circumvented by resetting identity in Tor, I suspect this may be some form of IP address-based ban, as presumably, many spammers and trollers also use Tor to abuse the site.

Is this really just an unexpected error or is it possible for an IP address to become banned from registering accounts? If so, why present this in the form of an *Error* instead of a *You cannot register at this time due to the volume of accounts being registered to post spam and abuse from your network* type message?

Comment: Possible duplicate. There are automatic IP bans. See: [Does the se network have an effective process in-place to deal with aggressively toxic users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364781/does-the-se-network-have-an-effective-process-in-place-to-deal-with-aggressively). They apparently don't last for long, but the exact details may be kept a secret to avoid (additional) abuse.

Comment: Somewhat related: A feature request to _implement_ this feature: [Can new account creation be rejected for SpamRammed IP addresses?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300883)